# Projection query using ancestor throws error 400

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

The following data is being added to datastore by doing something like this:

```
    key = ds.key(
            'User', 'alice',
            'id'
        )

    entity = datastore.Entity(
        key=key,
    )

    entity.update({"data": "big amount of information"})
    entity.update({"property_name": "confidential"})
    ds.put(entity)
```

Then, to reduce resources usage, I have tried to use projections query to get only small properties and ignore "data" which is really big by doing the following:

```
    key = ds.key(
        'User', 'alice'
    )
    query = ds.query(ancestor=key)
    query.projection = ["property_name"]

    entities = list()

    for entity in query.fetch():
        entities.append(entity)

    return entities
```

but I get this error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Unable to plan or invalidate query.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ancestor queries require a composite index even if you are projecting a single property. Make sure you have done that.

Comment: You mean by setting up a index.yaml file? I saw in the docs that indexing is automatic.. that is why i did not look into it.. also, I am not in production

Comment: Yes, using index.yaml. There are built-in indexes and then there are composite indexes. Built-in indexes are automatic for properties which don't specify explicitly  not to index. However, built-in indexes are global indexes and not suitable for ancestor queries. That's why you need a composite index, even though on only one property and specify "ancestor: yes" in the index definition.